# WCF Windows service permissions problem

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have created a WCF service and hosted it using Windows Services host.
To install the project I created an installation project (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic4)).
In the tutorial, it says to define in the ProjectInstaller.cs the `serviceProcessInstaller1` *Account* property to be *Network Service*. 
When using this setting the service did not started on the server. When I tried to start the process manually, it immediately returned to *stopped* state.

After when I changed the *Account* to *LocalSystem* the service works properly.
My questions are:

1. Any ideas why it won't work with Network Service account?
2. What are the security implications of using a server with *LocalSystem* account? This server is used locally in the intranet as a reporting server for other servers.

Comment: Its going to be a user rights issue.  I'm not sure which right it is, but I'm pretty sure NS has less rights than LS.

Comment: True, but according to the tutorial it should be possible to get it to work with NS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Network Service does not have proper priviligies to run a WCF host using named pipes (see http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/12/dealing-with-os-privilege-issues-in-wcf-named-pipes-scenarios.html).
2. See http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/services/understanding-the-local-service-and-network-service-accounts.aspx for a description about the differences between those accounts. The LocalSystem is a local administrative account that can cause a lot of trouble if exploited by an attacker. The Network Service account has much less access and is because of that better to use.